# Why use lag 12 autocorrelation to test January effect?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, lags

[image]

I don't understand this example. Why use lag 12 autocorrelation to test January effect.

Comment: A lag 12 autocorrelation on monthly data would measure if a given months returns are linearly related to the same months returns in a prior year.  I certainly doesn't single out an specific month.  I think you're right to be confused.

Comment: As a side comment, it's bad practice to scan a page and post an image of it.  It is more work to type it out, but it greatly helps the usability of the site.  Some of our users interact with the site with other senses than vision, and they cannot interpret your question, which is a shame, because it seems like a good question.

Comment: This isn't how I would test the January effect, but if returns are higher in January, you indeed would see a positive autocorrelation at the 12 month lag and a slightly negative autocorrelation at lower lags.

Comment: The interpretation at the end is blatantly incorrect: the data merely *suggest* there is a nonzero lag-12 correlation.  They could just as well be consistent with an annual drop in stock prices in July.

Comment: @whuber This is exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 4):

Let $j_{t}$ be an indicator that month $t$ is January. Imagine the return process is:

$$r_t = \mu + b j_t + \epsilon_t$$

Where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise process. Mean returns are higher in January. Technically, this isn't a stationary process but let's hand wave around that for a second.

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(r_t, r_{t-12} \right) &= \operatorname{Cov}\left(\mu + bj_t + \epsilon_t, \mu + bj_{t-12}+ \epsilon_{t-12} \right)\\
&= b^2 \operatorname{Cov}(j_t, j_{t-12})
\end{align*}

Remember that $j_t$ is an indicator for whether month $t$ is January, so $\operatorname{Cov}(j_t, j_{t-12}) > 0$.

If this were the data generating process and you ran a regression of returns $r_t$ on $r_{t-12}$, you'd get a positive coefficient (with sufficient data).

Note that this test isn't specific to January. If an effect were specific to February or any other month, it would also create positive autocorrelation at lag 12.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm picturing a blob of points that are the other months and their lags, and then a smaller blob to the upper right that are the Januaries and their lags.